# Distinct values on Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2008

I want to show the distinct values of a table column on Crystal report Text field. The column name is DO_NO and  values are

1. CR126069
2. CR127133
3. CR127133
4. CR127133
5. CS100521

Now I need to show this data like CR126069,CR127133,CS100521 in a text field.
Please help!

Comment: Please edit your question add more details to your question that shows where this above data comes from and how you bind this data to crystal report

Answer (score 0):

1. create one formula using following code then placed this formula in details section, here "TEST" is the table name and "DO_NO" is the column name.
   //1st Formula

   ```
   WhilePrintingRecords;
   stringvar array arr;
   numbervar i;
   if not({TEST.DO_NO} in arr) then
   (
       i := i + 1;
       redim preserve arr[i];

       arr[i]:= {TEST.DO_NO} &"," ;
   );
   arr[i]
   ```

   2. After that create one more  formula using below code and place it into Footer.

   //2nd formula

   ```
   WhilePrintingRecords;
   stringvar array arr;
   stringvar fin;
   numbervar j;
   for j := 1 to ubound(arr) do
   fin := fin + arr[j];  
   left(fin,len(fin)-2);
   ```